# Why are there limits on physics' applicability?

Tags: biology, determinism

(Not sure if this is the right SE for this question).

Physics is great at predicting what inanimate stuff do. Why can't it also predict what living things do? For example, if I throw a ball off a cliff then 
I can predict that it'll move in a parabola. If I throw a person off a cliff I can also predict that he'll move in a parabola, but I can't predict if he'll land with his left hand pointing up or not, since he can choose to make my prediction wrong.

In principle, the motion of all particles that make up the person is deterministic (up to quantum uncertainty), which should imply that the motion of the person is also deterministic. But it isn't. The only thing I can think of that can create this uncertainty is quantum mechanics, but by Bell's theorem QM is fundamentally unpredictable. If QM is the root reason we can't predict living behavior, that should imply everything we do is random, e.g. "I choose to drive to work today, but halfway there I might choose to drive to a cinema instead", which is obviously not the case.

It seems clear to me that physics fundamentally fails to predict living beings. Hence the question: why?

EDIT: I don't consider this a duplicate of [Are living organisms deterministic?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/281025/) because it assumes that living organisms are not deterministic, and asks why. The answers in that question also deal with "total" determinism, not determinism in the quantum sense, which is also addressed in this question.

Comment: Determinism is a red herring. Sheer complexity makes prediction difficult. Even very simple deterministic systems can be hard to predict if they're big enough, the classic example being cellular automata, like Conway's Game of Life.

Comment: Your only example of an unpredictable phenomenon is human choice. Are there other examples you want addressed, or is that really the crux of your argument?

Comment: equations of motion applied to real-life situations are never solvable exactly. From complexity arises chaos which means even the slightest change in initial conditions can result in a completely different outcome, which is unpredictable. Plus deterministic classical physics is just an approximation to quantum mechanics, which in turn is just an approximation to quantum field theory, etc. etc.

Comment: E.g., [here](http://www.conwaylife.com/w/index.php?title=Twin_prime_calculator) is a Life pattern that starts with 3062 active cells in a 440x294 bounding box which emits spaceships based on the sequence of twin primes. If the [twin prime conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime) is true, it will emit spaceships forever (assuming you can give it enough RAM to run in), if the conjecture is false, it will eventually stop emitting them.

Comment: @MitchellPorter if you can think of other examples I would be interested in those as well, although it's hard to prove that those examples really are unpredictable.

Comment: @PM2Ring yes in practice sheer complexity makes prediction difficult, but in principle it's doable, which is what matters for this question.

Comment: @Allure What's your proof that *choice* is unpredictable? Is it because you can deliberately do the opposite of what someone else predicts? You can program a computer to 'do the opposite' too.

Comment: @MitchellPorter as in, if I hurl a robot off a cliff, I can't predict if it will land with its left hand pointing up either? Investigating the robot's source code should, however, give some predictive power, e.g. I should be able to tell if it will "always" do the opposite, and if not, how likely it is to not do the opposite; further if a RNG is involved I should be able to predict what the RNG is going to output, etc.

Comment: @Allure So if you had analogous data about a person's brain, could you predict their choices?

Comment: @MitchellPorter seems implausible to me (humans are irrational, and not something that works by algorithm) although I concede I can't be sure.

Comment: It seems plausible that if I hurl a human of a cliff and repeat the experiment under the exact same initial condition, that the outcome will also be indentical. Of course, it is actually impossible to repeat the experiment under exactly the same circumstances. (The fact that I did the experiment before already makes it different.) That humans are irratic and irrational does not mean they are random.

Comment: Your logic is flawed. Randomness exists at the classical level. Classical thermodynamics and the law of entropy increase are not based on quantum mechanics. You also cannot predict intelligent robot's behavior based on the source code. It is a wide spread misconception that computers are only algorithmic. Totally wrong. Computers also perform real data stream processing where the outcome is defined by the environmental data that changes every second, not by algorithms. There is no conceptual difference between humans and intelligent robots and no reason to assume quantum randomness in humans.

Comment: If you "predict" that a ball thrown from a cliff moves in a parabola, you will be wrong, because you are ignoring several features of the motion (the most important one being air resistance). *Nothing* in physics is a prediction about the "real world". Everything is a prediction about a *model* of the "real world" - and that is still true even if the model includes quantum mechanics!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are living organisms deterministic?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/281025/)

Comment: @safesphere but in principle, one can know the environmental data with exquisite precision and that would make the robot's behavior predictable. Classical thermodynamics is only random because we can't model the particles themselves. Again in principle, with knowledge of the positions and velocities of every particle coupled with sufficient computing power, we can predict where they'll be in the future.

Comment: @alephzero I actually edited air resistance out of the question when I was composing it since I don't view it as central to the question. It certainly complicates things, but I don't see it as fatal (in principle).

Comment: @Allure Your assumptions are incorrect. You could "in principle" know the environment only in a computer model, not in reality. Determinism is an obsession of an insecure mind. The actual reality is a balance of randomness and determinism. However, hypothetically, ***if*** you could know the environment, then you'd be able to predict intelligent robots and humans equally. Intelligence is software. It doesn't matter what hardware it runs on, carbon or silicon, in principle.

Comment: To reopen this post (v3), consider a less broad title question.