# Why do the laws of physics fail to predict the behavior of frustrators?

Tags: chaos-theory, determinism, laws-of-physics

This is my attempt to make [an earlier question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/411533/25301) less broad. This question takes the form of a thought experiment, and is based on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iSfXdNIolQA).

Suppose you are given:

- The positions, velocities, wavefunctions, masses, whatever you want to know of every single particle in the experiment
- Unlimited computing power
- As much time as you want

You are asked to use these things to predict whether a certain light bulb A will be on or off at 12pm on a specified date. The only requirement is that at 11:55pm, you must toggle another light bulb B on or off. If B is on, then you are predicting that A will also be on at noon. If B is off, then you are predicting that A will also be off. Naively, this seems like it's doable. After all, the laws of physics enable us to evolve initial conditions forward in time. Every law of physics from $F = ma$ to Schrodinger's equation works in this way.

The problem: light bulb A is hooked up to a detector that detects whether light bulb B is on or off, as well as a computer which sets A to be off if B is on, and vice versa (called a "frustrator" in the video). Now physics seems to fail completely. We can't make any accurate predictions!

The video deals with free will, but this question has a different focus. Given that frustrators are well-defined (classical, even) systems and not impossible theoretical constructs, why do the laws of physics suddenly fail so catastrophically? What is so special about frustrators that nullifies physics' predictive power?

Comment: I don't see where any laws of physics are failing here or why we can't predict bulb A. If B is on, then A is off, according to your description. Is something missing in the description?

Comment: This seems to be a free will/philosophy issue so is probably off topic. In any case, I can always predict what will happen, its just set up so that I can't register my prediction in the way you ask me to. (However, I know to my own satisfaction what is going to happen).

Comment: This is reminiscent of both supertasks (e.g. flickering a lamp on and off with shrinking intervals like $2^{-n}$; what is the state after time 2?) and the Norton dome problem. Physics can get around supertasks by arguing that they cannot be done with the resources that exist in the universe - you just get a somewhat messy approximation. The dome problem however suggests that there might be indeterminacy even in simple physical theories.

Comment: @AndersSandberg I think all the dome shows you is that if you are a bit casual about smoothness conditions then theories predict odd things.

Comment: @Steeven, the predictor won't predict correctly state of the bulb A, because the system is set up to use that prediction and make it incorrect.

Comment: @jacob1729, if you could predict correctly, before 11:55, the state of the bulb A at 12:00, surely you could set up the bulb B state so as to beat the frustrator. But the assumption is that the frustrator cannot be beaten, so the only possibility is you can't predict A. The only thing you could predict is that only one bulb will be on after 12:00.

Comment: @JánLalinský Hm, my point was that I can easily predict what the state of the lamp will be. I write down on a sheet of paper "off" and then turn lamp B on. The sheet of paper is always correct, its just that this very specific way of registering my prediction (via lamp B) doesn't work. Likewise, if I want to register my prediction of a particle's trajectory, I'd better not do so by deciding to leave a roadblock in its way.

Comment: @jacob1729 yes that would happen as you say, but the point of the argument is that if the frustrator works (assume it can read you paper), then successful prediction is not possible.

Comment: @JánLalinský I do understand the description and the experiment. But it does not show any violation of the laws of physics. If I require you to do something impossible, and you thus can't do it, then that doesn't break any law of physics.

Comment: @Steeven I think the word 'violation' carries implications that aren't in the question. The laws of physics can "fail" but still remain "unviolated" - e.g. in a strong wind then a naive measurement of conservation of momentum in a 2-body collision might not hold, but that's because the experiment is poorly designed and not because the laws of physics are being violated.

Comment: @Steeven I agree there is no violation of laws of physics.

Comment: @Allure Okay, I see where you are heading, but this is a stretch. In that poorly designed experiment, the laws of physics aren't violated - but they also aren't failing. They are just not taken fully into account. "Violated" and "failing" mean the same thing here in my mind - but no need to start a debate over simple wording.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Given that frustrators are well-defined (classical, even) systems and not impossible theoretical constructs, why do the laws of physics suddenly fail so catastrophically? What is so special about frustrators that nullifies physics' predictive power?

The laws of physics do not fail in that thought experiment. The experiment (with frustrator) is an interesting aspect of determinism but is not a conclusive argument against determinism in physics.

The author also didn't mean it that way. He meant to illustrate, via a physical model, that if the very predictions about future state of the system (at 12:00) are set to influence the system at earlier time (at 11:55), those predictions may fail, even while some external observer would see that everything, including the failed prediction, was completely determined by the past state.

In that physical example with frustrator, the failure of the predictor to predict is due to the fact that the predictor is coupled physically with the system to be predicted and in a way that prevents successful prediction. This strange predictor *determines* what will happen to the system, instead of predicting it. Thus, it is a bad predictor, but a good controller.

This is non-standard use of deterministic predictor from standpoint of physics. The standard use is to predict the future state, on a paper, verbally or in a computer, without any influence on the system. There may be some other predictor which is not made to interfere with the system, whose predictions will work out.

In real life as opposed to theoretical considerations, the reason why deterministic model based predictions fail is mostly because of errors in calculation, or in the initial state data, or because the model is bad.

The frustrator example shows an interesting aspect of determinism: if the physical process performing the calculation influences the system that is being predicted, the influence may be of such kind that prediction may turn out to be incorrect or impossible. One example that comes to mind: if calculation of future state of atmosphere is done using too many computers, the calculation itself will heat the atmosphere and influence the actual future state. Sometimes this effect can be taken into account by the model, but sometimes, as in the frustrator example, it can't.